# Node.js puppeteer - How to fetch only certain (filter) records from a table

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using node.js and puppeteer to get some data. From the targeted table I only want to fetch certain records though .... . More specific, records with innerText: 'file. ........ .idx'.

The below shows my query:

```
const tableRows = await page.$$('table > tbody tr');
console.log(tableRows.length);

let tableCell01;
let tableCell01Val;

for (let i=1; i < tableRows.length; i++){

  tableRow = tableRows[i];
  tableCell01 = await tableRow.$('td:nth-child(1) a');
  tableCell01Val = await page.evaluate( tableCell01 => tableCell01.href, tableCell01 );

  console.log('\n');
  console.log(tableCell01Val);

}
```

And here the output without the filtering is:

Console:

```
6

file.20180702.idx
file.20180703.idx
file.20180705.idx
sitemap.20180702.xml
sitemap.20180703.xml
sitemap.20180705.xml
```

So the desired result should be:

Console:

```
3

file.20180702.idx
file.20180703.idx
file.20180705.idx
```

What's the best way to do this? Best would be to filter already before the loop ... to also get the correct tableRows.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`page.$x()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagexexpression) to check the value of the `href` attribute with an XPath expression before selecting the rows:

```
const tableRows = await page.$x( '//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[starts-with(@href, "file.")]/../..' );
```

Result:

```
3

file.20180702.idx
file.20180703.idx
file.20180705.idx
```

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to use XPath for this.  I prefer using CSS selectors instead.

Comment: @jnylen Looks like a perfect opportunity to me. No need to over-complicate things.

Comment: It may just be personal preference, but I like to use the "standard" query language built in to the browser, CSS, JS, etc, rather than adding another one.

Comment: @jnylen You are entitled to your personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`page.$$eval`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.7.0/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) (evaluate a function against an array of elements matched by a selector).  This will do all of the required operations in a single call to the browser.

Pseudocode (assumes that all first-child `td`s have an `a` child):

```
const hrefArray = await page.$$eval( 'table > tbody tr', trs => {
    return trs.map( tr => {
        return tr.querySelector( 'td:nth-child(1) a' ).href;
    } ).filter( href => /^file.*idx$/.test( href ) );
} );
```